# Deep linking from URI in other apps

Tags: android, uri, intentfilter, deep-linking

I'm having some problems with URI's with deeplinking. I've got it working with `myapp://a?parameter=1` but... My problem is, this URL will be send by SMS and in for example the hangouts app it's impossible to click on this link because it's not a http URL.

I can't change the URI to a `http://myapp`, this is because the iPhone variant doesn't support this way. I need a way to click the `myapp://` from other apps such as Hangouts.

My code in the manifest is:

```
        <intent-filter android:label="label">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "myapp://a” -->
            <data android:scheme="myapp" android:host="a" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Is there a possibility to add the `myapp://` prefix to the android system in some way or make the link clickable in other apps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know of a solid solution to this, but I have it working by using a server-side redirect using PHP. The code:

```
<?php

// Set App deeplink
$app_url = 'fb://profile/33138223345';

// Try to redirect the device to the URL
header('Location: ' . $app_url);

?>
```

This will simply redirect the user to the Facebook app. This way you get an HTTP url that will work pretty much anywhere.

I have this script online, simple use you device and go to [this page](http://www.donovansolms.com/deeplink.php). It should open the Facebook app and navigate to the Wikipedia page on iOS and Android.

The easiest solution would be to use a URL shortening service and just get an HTTP link for the deeplink, but I could not find any shortners that supports this.

Hope this helps!

Comment: It did help, thanks! However the perfect way would work without internet, but this isn't possible.